# Multiple rzslider inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside ng-repeat, i need to have multiple "rzslider" which are not dependent on each other.

If I have multiple sliders, changing one slider changes the other slider value. How can i have multiple sliders not dependent on each other?

Comment: What you had tried?

Comment: have you assigned separate models and options to every slider

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

- lightsData : Array of objects

  ```
          <div ng-repeat = "light in lightsData track by $index">
               <div class="source-header">
                   <input type="checkbox" id="{light_$index}" style="opacity: 1;" class="checkbox" ng-change="update()"  ng-model="light.nativeLightObject.visible">
                   <label for="{light_$index}" class="source-name">{{light.name}}</label>
               </div>
               <rzslider class="lsslider" rz-slider-model="light.nativeLightObject.intensity" rz-slider-options="option"></rzslider>       
               <div class="col-md-12 divider"></div>
           </div>
  ```